# How to clear HTML content already sent to the browser, without JavaScript?

Tags: html, http, browser

Bugzilla, Mozilla's issue tracker, has a nice loading screen while the search is being executed. In the days of Ajax, this is nothing special. They do it without any scripting, though, and I want to know how.

For example:

1. Disable JavaScript
2. Open the following URL:
    https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?short_desc=IDL&resolution=---&resolution=DUPLICATE&query_format=advanced&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr

You get a page with an animated image, the text "Please wait while your bugs are retrieved." and a title of "Bugzilla is pondering your search".

## Update:

This is the entire DOM while the search is being executed. No meta refresh, no scripts.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bugzilla is pondering your search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="margin-top: 15%; text-align: center;">
            <center>
                <img width="160" height="87" alt=""
                     src="extensions/BMO/web/images/mozchomp.gif">
            </center>
            <h1>Please wait while your bugs are retrieved.</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

After a while, the results page appears. The previous HTML vanishes and a completely new DOM appears, including a new title "Bug List".

So my question is: how does this work exactly? Please don't list alternative techniques - I am not interested in loading screens at all, but want to use that exact mechanism for something completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you look at the souce of the page you see you actually get two responses each with its own header

```
WARNING: YOUR BROWSER DOESN'T SUPPORT THIS SERVER-PUSH TECHNOLOGY.
--------- =_y97AELt1tHMqcK8D
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bugzilla is pondering your search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="margin-top: 15%; text-align: center;">
      <center><img src="extensions/BMO/web/images/mozchomp.gif" alt=""
      width="160" height="87"></center>
      <h1>Please wait while your bugs are retrieved.</h1>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>

--------- =_y97AELt1tHMqcK8D
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
content-disposition: inline; filename="bugs-2011-08-30.html"
Set-Cookie: {data}
Set-Cookie: {data}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bug List</title>
{the rest of the request}
```

I'm not too sure about the browser support for this except for mozilla...

Comment: Looks like this is `multipart/x-mixed-replace`, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push . The article mentions it "was introduced by Netscape in 1995" and "is still supported by Firefox, Opera and Safari today, but ignored by Internet Explorer".

Answer (score 0):

Use a [meta refresh tag](http://www.webworkshop.net/auto-redirecting_methods.html) to reload the page every N seconds.

Return the "please wait page" (with the meta tag) as long as the search results are collected.

Return the results page (*without* the meta tag) when the results are ready.

You should be able to see what is happening when you open Firebug (or similar) and open the Network tab.